# Emulate non public Azure Cloud for testing purposes

Tags: azure, azure-storage-emulator, azurite

As the question reports, I was wondering if there is a way to emulate resources hosted in a non public Azure Cloud (ex. Gov Azure, Germany Azure, China Azure, ...)

I've found out **Azurite** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio) but it seems related to public Cloud, and in particular to storage account.

I ask this because sometimes I've code application which run without any issues in public cloud environment but it breaks on other non cloud env (for example issue with authentication using Managed Identity because maybe the Authority is missing and things like that) and since I've not access to such environments, a way to emulate that and run some integration tests around that would be very useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio) is just a local emulator for Blob Storage, Queue Storage and Table storage that can be used for simulating the Azure cloud during development and testing purposes in your local environment. Please note that the Azurite is not designed to emulate resources hosted in a non-public Azure cloud.

If you want to use a non-public cloud (private), you could leverage the [Azure Stack Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-overview?view=azs-2206). If you want to try for free, see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/contact/azure-stack-dev-kit/). This will help you to have your own cloud which run completely or partially disconnected from the internet and the public cloud.